# Problems with IE7

Tags: bug, status-completed, internet-explorer-7

I've had a few issues using the site from IE7 today (I can't update the browser, although I do have access to another one indirectly which I'm posting this from), which have recently gotten worse (I can't vote and the helper toolbar isn't there when editing questions).

It's reporting an error:
Line 2:
Char: 46983
Error: Expected identifier, string or number
Code: 0
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

URL changes, according to the page, but the error seems consistent (at least for questions/ask a question), it's at a different point for the new questions page..

Comment: IE 7 is only [minimally supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208). **Time to upgrade your browser.** Chrome is nice.

Comment: I'm having the same problems in IE8.  I'm in a corporate environment, so I don't get to control when they upgrade IE, and I don't think supporting one version back is unreasonable.  I had to type this in Firefox because I couldn't get comments to work in IE8 this morning.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I hoped minimally supported included voting :)  Company policy doesn't allow later versions of IE yet on desktops.  I can access Chrome on a VPC, that doesn't usually have internet connectivity, so it's far from ideal...  Although you're right, it does play nicely with SO.

Comment: @Robert Are you running in compatibility view on IE8? I'm not getting this issue on my IE8.

Comment: @Grace: Ah, how 'bout that?  I'm typing comments in IE8 now. :) Don't know why IE8 decided to suddenly slip into compatibility mode.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. I wasn't necessarily *endorsing* the IE 7 support policy. It does seem reasonable to still be fully supporting that browser to me. I just found it hard to believe that very many developers would be working in an environment where they weren't allowed to install software on their machine, or locked into a particular version of IE. I'd be my IT department's nightmare...

Comment: @Cody - It does work most of the time, but some days - like this afternoon CET - IE7 complains on the JavaScript and that disables comments and voting, but not posting answers and editing. Partially supported? -:)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There was once a browser from Redmond
That of trailing commas was not fond.
That browser is old,
But some users are bold,
Keep using it fearless like James Bond.

There was once a hacker from Britain,
Who wanted some code to be written.
He added a comma,
Yeah, that was a bummer
For the poor IE7-using kitten.

There was once a German named Ben,
who removed that one comma again.
And since he had time,
He then started to rhyme,
'bout having rescued IE-loving men.

Comment: So, 'comma' and 'bummer' rhyme?

Comment: Oh, so it was Marc's fault? `:P`

Comment: @jjinguy: You ought to say it with a thick American accent... it comes out as 'bumma'

Comment: @yoda, I don't think tat's how Americans say it. (I don't for sure)  Maybe it's Australian?

Comment: @balpha: That's great, thanks for looking after us Brits :)

Comment: @jjnguy: The comma/bummer thing is called "artistic freedom". And yes, it was Marc's fault :)

Comment: It probably took you longer to write this poem than it did to fix the error. :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Just a tiny bit :)

Comment: Why in limericks? Limericks are so uncouth. Haikus show true class.

Comment: @mmyers: Poetry is free / Limericks; forgotten art / You, Sir, are wrong.

Comment: You doubt the haiku? Its beauty is its order; brevity breeds strength.

Comment: Wow you can sell this to Microsoft and get serious $$$! ;) Seriously now - has this already been delivered? Saw more recent report from 7 hours ago.