# Problems logging in from my Windows Phone 7 device

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, mobile-web, internet-explorer-7

For the past few days it doesn't seem possible anymore to login to Stack Overflow (or any other variant) from my [Windows Phone 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_7) device. When I go to the login page it only shows me the *recover your account* information, not the icons to choose by which service you want to login.

Anyone having the same experience? Or have a solution? I have tried both the desktop version as wel the mobile version setting in Internet Explorer, but both didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another [trailing comma issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91656/problems-with-ie7/91663#91663) (unfortunately, the WP7 browser is essentially an IE7).

Fixed in the next build (of Stack Overflow; not of Windows Phone, I fear).

Comment: I seem to recall that www.jslint.com/ check for this sort of thing, but is is many years since I was last forced to write jscript

Comment: @IanRingrose: JSLint is useless for our JavaScript, because we don't adhere to quite a few of Douglas Crockford's conventions (and I admire him, don't get me wrong) -- so the signal-to-noise ratio in the JSLint reports is way too low.